# Aggregate Totals From Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some market feed data that i'm trying to use **mongodb 3.4.5** on Ubuntu 16.04 to produce a nice summary given a date range.

Here is one example document.. each document might contain multiple batched data in Buys, Sells and Fills.

```
{
    "MarketName" : "BIX",
    "Nounce" : 12040,
    "Buys" : [ 
        {
            "Type" : 2,
            "Rate" : 0.08068147,
            "Quantity" : 55.57280163
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : 1,
            "Rate" : 0.07980372,
            "Quantity" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : 0,
            "Rate" : 0.07962334,
            "Quantity" : 34.96018931
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : 1,
            "Rate" : 0.07960592,
            "Quantity" : 0
        }
    ],
    "Sells" : [ 
        {
            "Type" : 0,
            "Rate" : 0.08070098,
            "Quantity" : 4.08189692
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : 0,
            "Rate" : 0.08112318,
            "Quantity" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : 1,
            "Rate" : 0.08112319,
            "Quantity" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : 1,
            "Rate" : 0.08149567,
            "Quantity" : 0
        }
    ],
    "Fills" : [ 
        {
            "OrderType" : "SELL",
            "Rate" : 0.08068147,
            "Quantity" : 0.51627134,
            "TimeStamp" : "2017-07-25T15:20:34.357"
        },
        {
            "OrderType" : "BUY",
            "Rate" : 0.08048147,
            "Quantity" : 0.51007134,
            "TimeStamp" : "2017-07-25T15:20:34.357"
        }
    ],
    "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-07-26T22:32:20.741+08:00")
}
```

What I've been trying with various unwinds and groups, projects and push etc.. but i'm not getting anywhere close to the output i want. Because the type is the object key name i am struggling to get something to group on.

The output i'm looking for is something like this.

```
{
    "MarketName" : "RRG",
    "Buys" : {
            totalCount:     99,                 //size/count of all items in Buys array
            avgRate:        0.07980372,         //avg rate of all buy object items
            totalQuantity:  3.09239812,         //sum of all buy array items, quantity values
            totalValue:     306.14741388,       //avgRate * totalQuantity
            type0: {
                totalCount:     19,             //count of items in Buy array oftype 0
                avgRate:        0.07980372,     //avg rate of all buy object items of type 0
                totalQuantity:  3.09239812,     //sum of all buy object quantity values oftype 0
                totalValue:     30.14741388,    //avgRate * totalQuantity
              },
            type1: {
                totalCount:     9,           
                avgRate:        0.07980372,   
                totalQuantity:  3.09239812,     
                totalValue:     30.14741388,    
              },
            type2: {
                totalCount:     12, 
                avgRate:        0.07980372,            
                totalQuantity:  3.09239812,   
                totalValue:     30.14741388,  
              }
    },
    "Sells" : {
      ..same as buys format
    },
    "Fills" : {
      ..same as buys format
    }
}
```

If someone could assist with this in any way i'd be very grateful.

Here is query i managed to get working, but it's a long way from what i want and i'm no mongo expert so struggling to know how to proceed.

```
db.getCollection('tinfo').aggregate(
[
        {
            $match: {
                '$and': [
                    {'Type':        {$eq: 'market'}},
                    {'TimeStamp':   {$lte: new Date()}},
                    {'TimeStamp':   {$gte: new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}},
                    {'MarketName':  {$eq: 'BIX'}}
                ]
            }
        },
        },
        { $unwind: "$Buys"  },
        { $unwind: "$Sells" },
        { $unwind: "$Fills" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id:      {_id: "$_id", type: "$Buys.Type"},
                count:    {$sum: 1},
                avgRate:  {$avg: "$Buys.Rate"},
                quantity: {$sum: "$Buys.Quantity"}                           
            }
        },{
           $project: {
               type:      "$_id.type",
               count:     1,
               avgRate:   1,
               quantity:  1,
               total:     {$multiply: ["$quantity", "$avgRate"]}
           } 
         },{
            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "_id" : "$_id._id"
                },
                "results"  : {
                    $push: {
                        "k": "$type",
                        "v": {
                            "count":    "$count",
                            "avgRate":  "$avgRate",
                            "quantity": "$quantity"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
])
```

Comment: What have you tried? Using named keys in output is never a fantastic idea and is just plain unsupported unless you use MongoDB 3.4 at least. How are these actually stored anyway? The document format seems to suggest it's already "somewhat pre-aggregated" in at least the sense that all the items seems to appear under the relevant `"MarketName"` already. So does this actually "cross documents"? Or is it **already** in it's own document, and you just want to change the format a little? Please explain.

Comment: In fact your own "comment" annotation seem to suggest that this is in fact just "document reshaping". Therefore the aggregation framework is not the best fit for such a purpose. You would be far better off simply "re-shaping" the data within client code, since the syntax of of the aggregation pipeline "purely for this purpose" and actually "not aggregating" anything, is far more **terse** than the equivalent client code. Seems to fall under the category of *"Just because you **can** does **not mean you should!**"* As a general point of advice.

Comment: The source document i posted is what i receive via a websocket feed. I just receive and save to mongo without modifying it in any way. What i want to do is summarize the received data based on my match statement i.e. data based on timestamp within last 30min period to produce a summary of this data in a output similar to the one i gave.

Comment: just to explain that the source document is just one received json from websocket feed.. they send 50+ per minute of same document with varying quantities of nested Buy, Sell and Fill entries. So i don't want to reshape really.. i want to consolidate all these received documents, and their nested data into one single output that shows a aggregate of their contained data during a specified time range.

Comment: I asked you more questions than that. Please answer them. And please answer them by placing the specific detail "in the question itself". People need not trawl through comments just to understand your question. You also need to clarify your comment about "timestamps". Which ones? Some are strings, and one appears to be a `Date` but you have clearly modified what it actually is in your post because it's **not in ISO format**.  But primarily explain what "timestamp" has to do with this at all.

Comment: And again I told you very directly that "versions of MongoDB Under 3,.4 **cannot produce your expected output format using "named keys"**. So you need to clarify a "version". Lot's of things missing from your question that **need** to be in there. Please amend to add the details. Also please show you at least made some attempt. A question asking for code with no attempt just looks like you are treating this as a "code writing service". Less time responding to comments and **more time editing the question please**.

Comment: ok thank you, i updated with version info and my query attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible, and note that I'm actually quite deliberately using the actual MongoDB 3.4 features "in the last stage only", which generally highlights that you do not really need them since the main output can be achieved without the "named keys" in output.

The general listing goes like this:

```
var endDate = new Date(),
    startDate = new Date(endDate.valueOf() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );

db.getCollection('tinfo').aggregate([
/*
  { "$match": {
    "TimeStamp": {
      "$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate
    }
  }},
*/
  { "$project": {
    "MarketName": 1,
    "combined": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$Buys",
          "as": "b",
          "in": {
            "ttype": "Buys",
            "Type": "$$b.Type",
            "Rate": "$$b.Rate",
            "Quantity": "$$b.Quantity"  
          }  
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$Sells",
          "as": "s",
          "in": {
            "ttype": "Sells",
            "Type": "$$s.Type",
            "Rate": "$$s.Rate",
            "Quantity": "$$s.Quantity"
          }    
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$Fills",
          "as": "f",
          "in": {
            "ttype": "Fills",
            "Type": "$$f.OrderType",
            "Rate": "$$f.Rate",
            "Quantity": "$$f.Quantity"
          }   
        }} 
      ]    
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$combined" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "MarketName": "$MarketName",
      "ttype": "$combined.ttype",
      "Type": "$combined.Type"
    },
    "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "avgRate": { "$avg": "$combined.Rate" },
    "totalQuantity": { "$sum": "$combined.Quantity" },
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "MarketName": "$_id.MarketName",
      "ttype": "$_id.ttype",
    },
    "Types": {
      "$push": {
        "k": { 
          "$concat": [ 
            "type",
            { "$cond": {
              "if": { "$eq": [ "$_id.ttype", "Fills" ] },
              "then": "$_id.Type",
              "else": { "$substr": ["$_id.Type",0,1] }
            }}
          ]
        },
        "v": {
          "totalCount": "$totalCount",
          "avgRate": "$avgRate",
          "totalQuantity": "$totalQuantity",
          "totalValue": { "$multiply": [ "$totalQuantity", "$avgRate" ] }
        }
      }    
    },
    "totalCount": { "$sum": "$totalCount" },
    "avgRate": { "$avg": "$avgRate" },
    "totalQuantity": { "$sum": "$totalQuantity" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.MarketName",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id.ttype",
        "v": {
          "totalCount": "$totalCount",
          "avgRate": "$avgRate",
          "totalQuantity": "$totalQuantity",
          "totalValue": { "$multiply": [ "$totalQuantity", "$avgRate" ] },
          "Types": "$Types"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {    
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [{ "k": "MarketName", "v": "$_id" }],
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$data",
            "as": "d",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$d.k",
              "v": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    [
                      { "k": "totalCount", "v": "$$d.v.totalCount" },
                      { "k": "avgRate", "v": "$$d.v.avgRate" },
                      { "k": "totalQuantity", "v":  "$$d.v.totalQuantity" },
                      { "k": "totalValue", "v": "$$d.v.totalValue" }
                    ],
                    "$$d.v.Types"
                  ]
                }
              }  
            }  
          }}  
        ]
      }
    }
 }}
])
```

The broad strokes of which are.

**Project a combined array** which is needed to avoid a "cartesian product" which would otherwise occur if you used [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on each array separately. So you want to combine all the arrays into a single one with a consistent format for later processing. This is what we do using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to do a little "reshaping" and identify which "ttype" so we know the "source" array.

**Gradually Group** Since the "totals" occur at different levels we first want to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the "inner" `"type"` property and then gradually work outwards until you get back to the top level. At each stage you do the other calculations such as the [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) on the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) results.

**Finally Reshape** Which is all essentially about `$arrayToObject` when used in the aggregation framework. Here we just supply everything as "key" and "value" pairs in array format ( also explaining the `"k"` and `"v"` as used in earlier stages ) so that this operator can "transform" into an object format with "named keys".

Of course that final stage can also be done in client code, but since the version is supported I include the actual pipeline stage to do it.

The output is then:

```
{
    "MarketName" : "BIX",
    "Buys" : {
        "totalCount" : 4.0,
        "avgRate" : 0.08000321,
        "totalQuantity" : 90.53299094,
        "totalValue" : 7.24292988610092,
        "type2" : {
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08068147,
            "totalQuantity" : 55.57280163,
            "totalValue" : 4.4836953275268
        },
        "type1" : {
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.07970482,
            "totalQuantity" : 0.0,
            "totalValue" : 0.0
        },
        "type0" : {
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.07962334,
            "totalQuantity" : 34.96018931,
            "totalValue" : 2.7836470398945
        }
    },
    "Sells" : {
        "totalCount" : 4.0,
        "avgRate" : 0.081110755,
        "totalQuantity" : 14.08189692,
        "totalValue" : 1.14219329101337,
        "type1" : {
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08130943,
            "totalQuantity" : 0.0,
            "totalValue" : 0.0
        },
        "type0" : {
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08091208,
            "totalQuantity" : 14.08189692,
            "totalValue" : 1.13939557014279
        }
    },
    "Fills" : {
        "totalCount" : 2.0,
        "avgRate" : 0.08058147,
        "totalQuantity" : 1.02634268,
        "totalValue" : 0.0827042018781396,
        "typeBUY" : {
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08048147,
            "totalQuantity" : 0.51007134,
            "totalValue" : 0.0410512912480698
        },
        "typeSELL" : {
            "totalCount" : 1.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08068147,
            "totalQuantity" : 0.51627134,
            "totalValue" : 0.0416535306300698
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the data provided of course. The actual "calcs" may vary in implementation ( I'm just following your own notes ), but this is the general structure to follow.

---

### Earlier Versions

As noted the output format here really does not need the new features of [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and `$arrayToObject` in order to get to the end result. All that is being transformed is the final document response on the cursor.

So if you look at the output before the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage is invoked you see:

```
{
    "_id" : "BIX",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "Buys",
            "v" : {
                "totalCount" : 4.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08000321,
                "totalQuantity" : 90.53299094,
                "totalValue" : 7.24292988610092,
                "Types" : [ 
                    {
                        "k" : "type2",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 1.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.08068147,
                            "totalQuantity" : 55.57280163,
                            "totalValue" : 4.4836953275268
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k" : "type1",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 2.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.07970482,
                            "totalQuantity" : 0.0,
                            "totalValue" : 0.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k" : "type0",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 1.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.07962334,
                            "totalQuantity" : 34.96018931,
                            "totalValue" : 2.7836470398945
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "Sells",
            "v" : {
                "totalCount" : 4.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.081110755,
                "totalQuantity" : 14.08189692,
                "totalValue" : 1.14219329101337,
                "Types" : [ 
                    {
                        "k" : "type1",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 2.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.08130943,
                            "totalQuantity" : 0.0,
                            "totalValue" : 0.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k" : "type0",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 2.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.08091208,
                            "totalQuantity" : 14.08189692,
                            "totalValue" : 1.13939557014279
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "Fills",
            "v" : {
                "totalCount" : 2.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08058147,
                "totalQuantity" : 1.02634268,
                "totalValue" : 0.0827042018781396,
                "Types" : [ 
                    {
                        "k" : "typeBUY",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 1.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.08048147,
                            "totalQuantity" : 0.51007134,
                            "totalValue" : 0.0410512912480698
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k" : "typeSELL",
                        "v" : {
                            "totalCount" : 1.0,
                            "avgRate" : 0.08068147,
                            "totalQuantity" : 0.51627134,
                            "totalValue" : 0.0416535306300698
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And we can easily do that same transformation in client code when processing the cursor using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) JavaScript functions as a shell example:

```
var endDate = new Date(),
    startDate = new Date(endDate.valueOf() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );

db.getCollection('tinfo').aggregate([
/*
  { "$match": {
    "TimeStamp": {
      "$gte": startDate, "$lt": endDate
    }
  }},
*/
  { "$project": {
    "MarketName": 1,
    "combined": {
      "$concatArrays": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$Buys",
          "as": "b",
          "in": {
            "ttype": "Buys",
            "Type": "$$b.Type",
            "Rate": "$$b.Rate",
            "Quantity": "$$b.Quantity"  
          }  
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$Sells",
          "as": "s",
          "in": {
            "ttype": "Sells",
            "Type": "$$s.Type",
            "Rate": "$$s.Rate",
            "Quantity": "$$s.Quantity"
          }    
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": "$Fills",
          "as": "f",
          "in": {
            "ttype": "Fills",
            "Type": "$$f.OrderType",
            "Rate": "$$f.Rate",
            "Quantity": "$$f.Quantity"
          }   
        }} 
      ]    
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$combined" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "MarketName": "$MarketName",
      "ttype": "$combined.ttype",
      "Type": "$combined.Type"
    },
    "totalCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "avgRate": { "$avg": "$combined.Rate" },
    "totalQuantity": { "$sum": "$combined.Quantity" },
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "MarketName": "$_id.MarketName",
      "ttype": "$_id.ttype",
    },
    "Types": {
      "$push": {
        "k": { 
          "$concat": [ 
            "type",
            { "$cond": {
              "if": { "$eq": [ "$_id.ttype", "Fills" ] },
              "then": "$_id.Type",
              "else": { "$substr": ["$_id.Type",0,1] }
            }}
          ]
        },
        "v": {
          "totalCount": "$totalCount",
          "avgRate": "$avgRate",
          "totalQuantity": "$totalQuantity",
          "totalValue": { "$multiply": [ "$totalQuantity", "$avgRate" ] }
        }
      }    
    },
    "totalCount": { "$sum": "$totalCount" },
    "avgRate": { "$avg": "$avgRate" },
    "totalQuantity": { "$sum": "$totalQuantity" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.MarketName",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id.ttype",
        "v": {
          "totalCount": "$totalCount",
          "avgRate": "$avgRate",
          "totalQuantity": "$totalQuantity",
          "totalValue": { "$multiply": [ "$totalQuantity", "$avgRate" ] },
          "Types": "$Types"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  /*
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {    
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [{ "k": "MarketName", "v": "$_id" }],
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$data",
            "as": "d",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$d.k",
              "v": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    [
                      { "k": "totalCount", "v": "$$d.v.totalCount" },
                      { "k": "avgRate", "v": "$$d.v.avgRate" },
                      { "k": "totalQuantity", "v":  "$$d.v.totalQuantity" },
                      { "k": "totalValue", "v": "$$d.v.totalValue" }
                    ],
                    "$$d.v.Types"
                  ]
                }
              }  
            }  
          }}  
        ]
      }
    }
 }}
 */
])
.map( doc => Object.assign(
  { "MarketName": doc._id },
  doc.data.map( d => ({
      "k": d.k,
      "v": Object.assign(
        Object.keys(d.v)
          .filter(k => k !== 'Types')
          .map( k => ({ [k]: d.v[k] }))
          .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{}),
        d.v.Types.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr.k]: curr.v }),{})
      )
  }))
  .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr.k]: curr.v }),{})
))
```

Which of course produces the exact same output:

```
    {
        "MarketName" : "BIX",
        "Buys" : {
            "totalCount" : 4.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08000321,
            "totalQuantity" : 90.53299094,
            "totalValue" : 7.24292988610092,
            "type2" : {
                "totalCount" : 1.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08068147,
                "totalQuantity" : 55.57280163,
                "totalValue" : 4.4836953275268
            },
            "type1" : {
                "totalCount" : 2.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.07970482,
                "totalQuantity" : 0.0,
                "totalValue" : 0.0
            },
            "type0" : {
                "totalCount" : 1.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.07962334,
                "totalQuantity" : 34.96018931,
                "totalValue" : 2.7836470398945
            }
        },
        "Sells" : {
            "totalCount" : 4.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.081110755,
            "totalQuantity" : 14.08189692,
            "totalValue" : 1.14219329101337,
            "type1" : {
                "totalCount" : 2.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08130943,
                "totalQuantity" : 0.0,
                "totalValue" : 0.0
            },
            "type0" : {
                "totalCount" : 2.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08091208,
                "totalQuantity" : 14.08189692,
                "totalValue" : 1.13939557014279
            }
        },
        "Fills" : {
            "totalCount" : 2.0,
            "avgRate" : 0.08058147,
            "totalQuantity" : 1.02634268,
            "totalValue" : 0.0827042018781396,
            "typeBUY" : {
                "totalCount" : 1.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08048147,
                "totalQuantity" : 0.51007134,
                "totalValue" : 0.0410512912480698
            },
            "typeSELL" : {
                "totalCount" : 1.0,
                "avgRate" : 0.08068147,
                "totalQuantity" : 0.51627134,
                "totalValue" : 0.0416535306300698
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok many thanks for such a amazing answer, i learned a lot more from this answer than from many books and blogs i've ready recently

Comment: @FloWoo The books and blog posts are "coming". But for now the general material is posted here instead. So there are quite a few more posts here, and particularly on the ["aggregation framework"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2313887+[aggregation-framework]) usage that should have a lot of relevance for most people.